# Version difference for strtotime('first day of last month')?

Tags: php, date

In a script that contains

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of last month'))
```

in version 5.3.10 (localhost) I get, for example, '2012-03-01'.

in version 5.2.17 (remote host) I get '1969-12-31'.

Is there an expression that will return expected (e.g., '2012-03-01') results for both versions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the [mktime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) function:

```
<?php 
echo date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,date('n')-1,1,date('Y'))); //2012-03-01
?>
```

<kbd>**[See In Action](http://codepad.org/wSrLhb2N)**</kbd>

Comment: ...or `strtotime('-'.(date('j') - 1).' days -1 month')`

Comment: You should post as an answer ;P, I tend to stay away from strtotime as you can do pretty much any date/time manipulation with a function thats been around since PHP 3 ;)

Comment: Big thanks.  I also needed last day, which is now `date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,date('n'),0,date('Y')))`

Comment: Won't this break when the previous month is December?

Comment: i dont get exact in server.i get 1969-12-01

Answer (score 5):

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of -1 month'))
```

Works fine on PHP 7.0

Answer (score 1):

That's a [known bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53778) from PHP 5.2.17

Comment: Yeah PHP 5.2.x is *waaay* out of date, consider updating your PHP version please. (@DaveRandom I edited a few seconds later)

Comment: But what you could do is a not so nice workaround: `date('Y-m', strtotime('last month')).'-01'` But for creating the date *just* with a string there's no chance

Comment: Ah, but it's my ISP's box.  I'll let them know; I'm sure they'll get on it...yeah, right!

Answer (score -1):

As simple as:

```php
date('Y-m-01')
```

The first day of any month always is 1.