# First day of last month in date function is not working?

Tags: php

I have the below code,

```
$lastmonthLastDay =   date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last day of last month"));
$lastmonthFirstDay= date('Y-m-d', strtotime("first day of -1 month"));
```

Which works exactly in localhost. But when i push this in live always return `1970-01-01`.

Is there anything i missed in server settings ? kindly advice

Comment: That's not MySQL's `date` function, is it?

Comment: Give us some information about your server.

Comment: @deceze yes sorry for the mistake.Removed it.Thanks

Comment: @PLB what information you need ? Kindly explain

Comment: PHP version - 5.2.17  and Operating system - linux

Comment: looks like a duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250208/version-difference-for-strtotimefirst-day-of-last-month

Comment: @Eswar   thanks Eswar its working fine now. PHp version in my server is 5.2.17. Now i changed like date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,date('n')-1,1,date('Y')));

Comment: There are other ways to accomplish this of course. But if it works locally, it should work on production server. Enable error reporting on that server and see if you get an error (such as date.timezone not set).

Comment: @Dinesh that's the same solution i gave ;-) And a working last day of the month. Please be fair and accept answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$firstDay = date('d-m-Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m", strtotime("-1 month")), 1, date("Y",strtotime("-1 month"))));
$lastDay = date('d-m-Y', mktime(-1, 0, 0, date("m"), 1, date("Y")));
```

It's a more universal way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit old but...
The standard DateTime class in PHP 5.x works nicely for this:

```
    $last_month = new DateTime('now');
    $last_month->modify('-1 month');
    echo "Last month: ".$last_month->format('Y-m-1 00:00:00')."\n";
```

The format is the same as those for the date() function.